# Facebook one-time password

Tags: facebook

Basically, I have tried sending “opt” to 32665 from a supported provider. What is returned is a Facebook mobile confirmation code instead of a temporary code.

Directly from Facebook's help:

> Use your mobile phone to send a text message with the letters "otp" to 32665. When Facebook receives this text message, we will send you an email asking you to confirm your mobile number. Once you have done this, you will receive the temporary 8-character code that will serve as a one-time password for your account.

Any ideas on how to get it to send me what I need?

Comment: Have you already confirmed your mobile and attached it with your Facebook account?

Comment: So did you make a typo or what? Your post says 'opt' but the Facebook message says 'otp'.

Comment: @Hydra: no, the mobile has not been confirmed, but the above instructions are for "If you do not have a confirmed mobile number on your account". It can then be confirmed via email instead of Facebook itself. ekaj: I did, apologies. However, both 'opt' and 'otp' return the same response.

Answer (score 1):

First, for reference, here's the **[original post from Facebook](http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=436800707130)**:

> Simply text "otp" to 32665 on your mobile phone (U.S. only), and
>   you'll immediately receive a password that can be used only once and
>   expires in 20 minutes. In order to access this feature, you'll need a
>   mobile phone number in your account.

Notice that it says "U.S. only" and that you'll need to have registered a mobile phone number for your account already. The wording here is somewhat different from what you quoted in your post. The date for this is October 2010. I don't know if yours is more recent or not.

I found a **[step-by-step guide](http://blog.zeltser.com/post/1319041093/why-facebook-one-time-passwords)**. It is not recent, but it doesn't seem as though the procedure has changed. It was written by someone that does information security for a living, and has very detailed instructions for what to do, in order to get a Facebook One Time Password.

Note that it is an **OTP** not an **OPT** as the questions mentioned in one part. That is important!

EDIT

I think I found **[your source](https://www.facebook.com/help/188579777858759/)** for getting a Facebook one time password, which may be more recent, as it includes a list of supported carriers outside the U.S. It gives

- directions for getting a code by email for an OTP if you **do not** have a confirmed mobile number, and
- directions for getting an 8-character OTP if you **do** have a confirmed mobile number.

I would suggest confirming your mobile number, as it seems more likely to work right.